# Ejb, Error in second method rolls back first method

Tags: java, ejb, scheduler, jta

I have poller scheduled like this

```
@Schedule(minute = "*/5", hour = "*", persistent = false)
public void pollTimer() {

    startfirstPoller();

    startsecondPoller();

}
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void startfirstPoller() {
// find all booking from database and update
bokingFacade.findAll();
    bokingFacade.update(booking);
}
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void startsecondPoller() {
// find all booking updated from database and update
bokingFacade.findAll();
    bokingFacade.update(booking);
}
```

The first method update some bookings, save them to database and second method use the updated information to process further and again update the database. The problem is changes doesn't reflect in the database until and unless second executes successfully. Moreover, exception in second method rollback the successful changes made by first method. Please let me know what is happening and how to make two method independent of each other.

Comment: @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void startfirstPoller() {
    // find all booking from database and update
    bokingFacade.findAll();
        bokingFacade.update(booking);
    }
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void startsecondPoller() {
    // find all booking updated from database and update
    bokingFacade.findAll();
        bokingFacade.update(booking);
    }

Comment: Please update the original question (clearly mark it as an update) with the new code with annotations please. The code in the comment is completely unreadable.

Comment: Did that....  I got it resolved by marking the edit() method in the facade class with the annotation. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that because you don't actually define the start and end of the transaction that it is managed by the container and spans the entire execution.

You can manage the transactions using annotations in java EE. Look up JTA which is the API for transactions.

Comment: I did that but still the problem persists.

Comment: Did that....  I got it resolved by marking the edit() method in the facade class with the annotation. Thank you...

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please accept the answer so this question is closed. If you have further questions, update the original or ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the code is that the `@TransactionAttribute` annotation has no effect at all. In your `pollTimer()` method you're doing a simple local method invocation, therefore the EJB container doesn't know that you want a new transaction for each of your poller methods.

If you inject an EJB with `@EJB`, the container injects only a proxy, therefore it can intercept the EJB method invocations and do the necessary work, like tx management. However, there is no interception in your case, because you're doing a local method invocation.

The following things happen in your case:

- At time-out the `pollTimer()` method starts running in a new tx managed by the container
- The first and the second poller method get invoked in the exact same tx.